# Refactoring method to be part of an interface

Tags: go, interface

I am an ex python dev sometimes struggling with the explicit nature of Go.
I am trying here to refactor some code in order to be able move a method from one structure to be part of an interface.
But the process seems weird to me, I wish to confirm I am not doing something incorrectly.

I have the following interfaces, structure and methods:

```
type Executing interface {
    Execute()
}

type MyExecuter struct {
     attribut1 string
}

//The function I wish to move
func (exe1 *MyExecuter) format() string {
    return fmt.sprintf ("formated : %s", exe1.attribut1) 
}


func (exe1 *MyExecuter) Execute() {
    //Executing
    fmt.Println(exe.format())
}



func GetExecuter () Executer{
    return MyExecuter{attribut1: "test"}
}
```

So here I have a generic interface Execute, this interface will be accessed by the object returned by the GetExecuter method.

Now, as part of the implementation of one of my Executer, I want to move the Format method as part of an interface.
So I am doing the following:

```
type Formatting interface {
    format() string
}

type Formatter struct {}

func (formatter *Formatter) format(exe1 *MyExecuter) (string) {
    return fmt.sprintf ("formated : %s", exe1.attribut1)
}
```

So I create a new interface, a new empty structure, and update my function to take as attribute my previous structure.

While this seems to work, it seems to me this is a bit convoluted. Specially the part where I need to add a reference to my initial object as attribute of the method. Am I doing something wrong here, or this is the right way?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Executer` implementation already implements the `Formatting` interface:

```
type Executing interface {
    Execute()
}

type Formatting interface {
    format() string
}

func (exe1 MyExecuter) format() string {
    return fmt.sprintf ("formated : %s", exe1.attribut1) 
}


func (exe1 MyExecuter) Execute() {
    //Executing
    fmt.Println(exe.format())
}

v:=MyExecuter{}
// Here, v implements Executing and Formatting interfaces
```

One thing to note here: Your code shows pointer receivers. That means the methods are defined for `*MyExecuter`, but not for `MyExecuter`. So you have to pass pointers to the struct instance for this to work. Or, as I did above, use the value receivers so the methods are defined for both `MyExecuter` and `*MyExecuter`.